# Android, displaying a transparent listview over the bottom half of current activity

Tags: listview, android-layout, overlay, android

I have a textbox (`EditText`) in middle of the screen (portrait mode) which i have tied to a `custom ListView`. When a user starts typing in the textbox, the listview appears under it. But it slides the other elements to the end of the listview.

This is the xml code i am using:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <EditText android:id="@+id/actxt_1" android:hint="Please fill"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left" android:layout_weight="2.0" />
    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_mylocation"
        android:layout_height="50dp" android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right" />
</LinearLayout>
<ListView android:id="@+id/list1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1.0"/>
<TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/usr_msg"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@color/solid_yellow"
    android:text="Select please" />
```

What I want to do is, to show the transparent/translucent listview with the original activity showing in the background. give it the overlay feel.

how can I achieve this ?

Thanks

Comment: If you are trying to achieve autocomplete, [see this](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-autocomplete.html).

Comment: well i tried auto complete, but was facing a peculiar problem with it. Autocomplete shows suggestions only after u type 2 characters and not after a single character. Is that how it is supposed to be ?

Comment: Perhaps if you post e.g. "How do I change autocomplete such that it starts after a single character rather than 2 characters?". There's probably a much simpler solution to that than this one. But in order to have overlapping views, you can use a FrameLayout.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:weightSum="4">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/databg" android:layout_weight="1">
        <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">
            <EditText android:id="@+id/etsearch" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_height="42dp"
                android:minHeight="42dp" android:layout_marginTop="20dp"></EditText>
            <Button android:layout_width="42dp" android:background="@drawable/simplesearch"
                android:layout_height="36dp" android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:id="@+id/twtsearch"></Button>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ListView android:id="@+id/listsearch"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="3" android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't show the bottom half of activity under the listview. The listview is not transparent i guess, any ideas why ?